# How to pass arguments to animation.FuncAnimation()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

How to pass arguments to `animation.FuncAnimation()`? I tried, but didn't work. The signature of `animation.FuncAnimation()` is

> class matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None, save_count=None, **kwargs)                 Bases: matplotlib.animation.TimedAnimation

I have pasted my code below. Which changes I have to make?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(i,argu):
    print argu

    graph_data = open('example.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs, ys)
        plt.grid()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,fargs = 5,interval = 100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain what 'did not work'?  Did you get a trace back?

Comment: The simple correct answer, to the question that you asked, is that  fargs need to be  a list - as per Ed Smith's answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check this simple example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("example.txt", delimiter=",")
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot([],[], '-')
line2, = ax.plot([],[],'--')
ax.set_xlim(np.min(x), np.max(x))
ax.set_ylim(np.min(y), np.max(y))

def animate(i,factor):
    line.set_xdata(x[:i])
    line.set_ydata(y[:i])
    line2.set_xdata(x[:i])
    line2.set_ydata(factor*y[:i])
    return line,line2

K = 0.75 # any factor 
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(x), fargs=(K,),
                              interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

First, for data handling is recommended to use NumPy, is simplest read and write data.

Isn't necessary that you use the "plot" function in each animation step, instead use the `set_xdata` and `set_ydata` methods for update data.

Also reviews examples of the Matplotlib documentation: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/.

Comment: thank you Jorge for wonderful answer. But set_xdata and set_ydata methods not working if we embed canvas in wxpython form. do you have any idea ?

Comment: Check this mini-adaptation using the wxPython backend, which is similar to the last example:   [http://pastebin.com/c1WSRRD7](http://pastebin.com/c1WSRRD7)

Comment: thanks .  I have done the same thing like ur implementation, but I have triggered the animate() when a option selected from the Drop down list. So when a option selected form the Drop down list animate() function was executed repeatedly for every given time.But nothing was displayed on the screen. Do you have any idea why that happens?

Comment: Check this example, using a ComboBox as animation selector: [http://pastebin.com/7v4h6VzD](http://pastebin.com/7v4h6VzD)

Comment: wow thats great , I was not setting the xlim and ylim . Is that necessary?

Comment: No, isn't strictly necessary, instead you can use relim() and autoscale_view() methods   to adjust limit to current data.

Comment: I have tried with those  relim() and autoscale_view()  they  dint work. Now I just commented relim() in your code and checked its not showing graph

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111667/discussion-between-vinaykp-and-jorge-de-los-santos).

Comment: Where are placing these methods?.. `relim()` and `autoscale_view()` must be placed in animate method, just after `set_xdata` and `set_ydata`.

Comment: yes, I hv placed  just after set_xdata and set_ydata

Answer (score 5):

### Intro

Below you will find an example of code how to pass an argument properly to the *animation.funcAnimation* function.

If you save all the code parts below as a single *.py* file you can call the script as follow in your terminal:
`$python3 scriptLiveUpdateGraph.py -d data.csv`
where *data.csv* is your data file containing data you want to display live.

### The usual modules import

Below is my script starting:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import argparse
import time
import os

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
```

### Some function

Here I declare the function that will be called later by the [*animation.funcAnimation*](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html) function.

```
def animate(i, pathToMeas):
    pullData = open(pathToMeas,'r').read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    colunmNames = dataArray[0].split(',')
    # my data file had this structure:
    #col1, col2
    #100, 500
    #95, 488
    #90, 456
    #...
    # and this data file can be updated when the script is running
    for eachLine in dataArray[1:]:
        if len(eachLine) > 1:
           x, y = eachLine.split(',')
           xar.append(float(x))
           yar.append(float(y))

   # convert list to array
   xar = np.asarray(xar)
   yar = np.asarray(yar)

   # sort the data on the x, I do that for the problem I was trying to solve.
   index_sort_ = np.argsort(xar)
   xar = xar[index_sort_]
   yar = yar[index_sort_]

   ax1.clear()
   ax1.plot(xar, yar,'-+')
   ax1.set_xlim(0,np.max(xar))
   ax1.set_ylim(0,np.max(yar))
```

## Process the input parameters

To make the script more interactive I have added the possibility to read input file with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d","--data",
                help="data path to the data to be displayed.",
                type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

## Call the function to do the animation

And know we are answering the main question of this thread:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(args.data,), interval=1000 )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're pretty much there, the following has a few minor tweaks basically you need to define a figure, use the axis handle and put `fargs` inside a list,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

def animate(i,argu):
    print(i, argu)

    #graph_data = open('example.txt','r').read()
    graph_data = "1, 1 \n 2, 4 \n 3, 9 \n 4, 16 \n"
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(float(x))
            ys.append(float(y)+np.sin(2.*np.pi*i/10))
        ax1.clear()
        ax1.plot(xs, ys)
        plt.grid()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=[5],interval = 100)
plt.show()
```

I replace `example.txt` with a hardwired string as I didn't have the file and added in a dependency on `i` so the plot moves.