# Timestamp not showing on python matplot graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python. I am trying to plot a simulated real time from a csv. I wanted to add one row at a time to the graph, but the problem is that the graph cannot be plotted with timestamp as an x-axis.
[image]

The image above is the dataset where 'End' is a timestamp and 'ElapS' is an integer.

I am trying to plot between ElapS as Y-axis and End as X-axis

```
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_values = []
y_values = []

i = 0
def nextRowY():
    global i
    global j
    j=i
    i+=1
    return df.loc[j,"ElapS"] # returns the next 'ElapS' in the table

def nextRowX():
    return df.loc[j,"End"] #returns the next 'End' in the table

def animate(i):
    x=nextRowY()
    y=nextRowX()
    y_values.append(x)
    x_values.append(y)
    plt.cla()
    plt.scatter(x_values, y_values)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('ElapS')
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 1000)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The output that I got is an empty graph. The examples that I found in the internet just put timestamp as x-axis and it just works, so I wonder why mine does not show anything.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323524/6505847)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323524/6505847 'this' does not seem to work for me though