# Make animation.FuncAnimation() in matplotlib "non-blocking"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am following the useful advice on this thread:
[How to pass arguments to animation.FuncAnimation()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111571/how-to-pass-arguments-to-animation-funcanimation)
for passing arguments into maptlotlib.

My issue is I have a device generating (x,y) coordinates at 200Hz.

I would like to plot the x,y position at a slower rate of about 20 Hz.

The issue with my code now is that after getting the first set of (x,y,) points, it goes into the animation.FuncAnimation function and stays there. I am trying to instead keep the (x,y,) data going at 200 Hz and only have the animation.FuncAnimation run at the desired, slower rate.

My code looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('dark_background')

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1, 1), ylim=(-1, 1))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
pointsFollower, = ax.plot([], [], marker='o', color = 'C0',ls="")





def init():
    pointsFollower.set_data([], [])
   
    return pointsFollower, 

def animate(i,factor):
    xFollower = (factor[0])
    yFollower = (factor[1])
    print("in anim loop:",xFollower,yFollower)
    pointsFollower.set_data(xFollower,yFollower)
    
    return pointsFollower,


def main():
    while True:
        # Wait for the next set of frames from the camera
        ##function here sets pipeline to device

        # Fetch pose frame
        ##function here gets x and y data.
        
        K = (data.translation.x,data.translation.y)
       
    
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(K,), init_func=init,
                                frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

        plt.show()
    

    pipe.stop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't think the `while True` in `main()` is necessary.

Comment: thanks for the comment -  but even without the `while True` I still only get one return of the x,y coordinates from the device and then get stuck in the animation loop.